# How to upload video to a server

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app i have to upload the video to the web server using `POST` method. For this iam using `UIImagePickerController`. But when i am selecting video from my `ImagePickerController` it is going on by showing "compressing Video". I have written picker `allowsEditing` to `NO` also and the video saved in photo library is of duration just 50 seconds only. But still i am getting the same. Immediate response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
NSURL *urlvideo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/uploadVideoIphone.php",appUrl];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *filePath = [urlvideo path];
[request addFile:filePath forKey:@"uploadfile"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:200];
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
NSLog(@"responseString %@",[request responseString]);
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```